# lerna run watch not working for one of two packages

Tags: json, yarnpkg, tsc, lerna, yarn-workspaces

## Background:

I have a lerna monorepo with yarn workspaces and two packages. I am using tsc as the TS compiler.

packages/module1/package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "build": " tsc && tsc -m es6 --outDir ./dist/esm && webpack --config webpack.config.js",

  }
```

packages/module2/package.json:

```
  scripts: {
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "build": " tsc && tsc -m es6 --outDir ./dist/esm && webpack --config webpack.config.js",
  }
```

root package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "lerna run build",
    "start:project": "lerna run start --scope=@project_name/project",
    "start:project:watch": "concurrently \"yarn build && lerna run watch\" \"yarn start:project\"",
  },
```

### Expected Behavior:

```
yarn start:project:watch will run the build scripts and the watch scripts for each package
```

E.g. modifying any file in either package will rebuild the project and reload the page in the browser.

### Current Behavior:

```
yarn start:project:watch will runs the build scripts and watch scripts for package1 only.
```

E.g. project is rebuilt when files in package1 are modified, but not rebuilt when package2 files are modified.

What might be going on and what could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

There are possibly 2 reasons for this to happen

- you are using `--scope` which is specific to a single package
- if you want dependent packages to be rebuilt then you should include the `--include-dependents` flag

However even if you fix both cases mentioned above it might still work incorrectly but Lerna and [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite) added a new `lerna watch` command that will help with this scenario which can be used in this way.

Watch for changes on package-1 or its dependents and run the "build" script on the scoped package and also its dependents:

```bash
$ lerna watch --scope=my-package-1 --include-dependents -- lerna run build --stream --scope=\$LERNA_PACKAGE_NAME --include-dependents
```